# How do I somehow require a specific session object to be set in my controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there an annotation/attribute which can be set on a controller method, to have that controller action require a specific key in my session to be set?

I'm looking for a way (other than forms authentication) to do some kind of smart authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend `ActionFilterAttribute` in your own class and override the `OnActionExecuting` method. This method will get fired before entering the action:

```
public class RequireSessionSet : ActionFilterAttribute {
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActinExecutingContext filterContext) {
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Foo"] == null) {
        // Redirect or do something.
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can annotate any action:

```
[RequireSessionSet]
public ActionResult Index() {
}
```

### Edit:

You can also get fancier and allow a property to be set in the attribute:

```
public class RequireSessionSet : ActionFilterAttribute {
  public string SessionKey { get; set; }

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActinExecutingContext filterContext) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SessionKey)) {
      SessionKey = "Default";

    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session[SessionKey] == null) {
        // Redirect or do something.
    }
  }
}

[RequireSessionSet(SessionKey="SpecialKey")]
public ActionResult Index() {
}
```